# ASP.NET w3wp memory usage - Bytes in all heaps low, Private Bytes high

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory

I have a situation whereby the total # Bytes in all Heaps according to ANTS Memory Profiler is small (about 200MB), but the total Private Bytes/Working Set-Private is around 1.26GB.

The breakdown is something like:

Dictionaries, strings, int arrays, etc: 200MB
Free space: 793MB

The performance counter graph shows the "# Bytes in all Heaps" staying very low consistently - but the Private Bytes and Working Set - Private counters going up in ramps as the app is used.

No action in particular corresponds to a given rise, it seems.

It doesn't look like there are big allocations, then frees - the # Bytes in All Heaps really is very very flat.  I've tried taking snapshots during all kinds of requests, including when the private bytes is ramping up - but there's simply nothing big being allocated, .NET wise.

What else can I try to diagnose?  I'm installing WinDbg and will see what i can try there, though I haven't used it for memory debugging before.

Comment: Too many private bytes while the #bytes in all heaps is constant is an indication that unmanaged memory is not released. Do you have objects that use unmanaged resources?

Comment: @Sjips, not as far as I know - this is a LOB, SQL-backed app.  Unmanaged memory according to the profiler is 260MB - breakdown is 105MB CLR, 27MB to managed code, 90MB to profiler.. the problem is the 790MB that's "Free Space", used by .NET but not allocated to objects - it's ".NET free space"